# Usuing the term "half/full blood" in current English

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, expressions

**Edited:**

I need to know in a casual or formal occasion, would it be possible to introduce the type of a relation between your half-sister or half-brother an you as below:

> 1- We are **half-blooded**. 
>   2- We are **of half-blood**. 
>   3- We are **full-blooded**. 
>   4- We are **of full-blood**.

If not, then, what is the natural way in current English to say something like that? I wonder if you help me with it.

Comment: A stepbrother or stepsister is usually the child of your stepmother or stepfather *from a previous relationship*. I think you are talking about a half-brother or half-sister.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those 4 things would normally be said about you and your half-brother or your half-sister.

Why not stick with "half-brother" or "half-sister"? Those are the correct terms. Fluent English speakers certainly understand them. They are idiomatic in casual or formal conversation, or in writing, and they sound perfectly natural.

Discussions using "full-blooded", "half-blooded", etc. may make people think you are discussing racial or ethnic characteristics, which may cause you trouble.